# How can I implement 2 different EMM solutions simultaneously on Android?

Tags: android, good-dynamics, intune

I have an android application which needs to integrate to 2 EMM's (Good Dynamics & Microsoft Intune). Both sdks require my activities and other subclasses to derive from the subclasses (which ultimately derive from the native ones) defined in their sdk instead of the native ones. Since java does not allow multiple inheritance, how can I make my application integrate with both EMM's simultaneously?

I am ok with making separate apk's integrated with individual sdk's.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Good Dynamics doesn't require you to subclass its Activity implementation; so long as you call activityInit() in your Activity.onCreate() methods, this will be enough. See the documentation under GDAndroid.

Answer (score 0):

For Android platform, we have the experience to design a framework to unify the MDM application framework among Citrix, AirWatch and BlackBerry Good using the module method in Android Studio, it works.

But for InTune, it is different with other MDM solutions on Android platform, it requires classes replacement, defines all the key event handlers as final to force developers to change the code structure from the root.

So for InTune, it doesn't work even if you could have multiple inheritance from Java.